# Adding a href link to a Var string/array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, href, var

I have a slider with a js code. Each slide has a title. I made the titles in a var string but is there a possibility to these items(titles) in this string?

But I have a string(array) like:

```
var titles = [
    'namefayee',
    'Champ App',
    'Shirt Design',
    'Post NL'
];
```

But I want the titles to link to different websites.

For example:
https://codepen.io/fay10/pen/yLJwYBB

This person has a title named VIEW case but in his code, he only uses one link to view a case but he has photos of more cases all with the same link. My question is how to get different links for every different case

```
var msLinks = new MomentumSlider({
    el: slidersContainer,
    cssClass: 'ms--links',
    range: [0, 3],
    rangeContent: function () {
        return '<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>';
    },
    vertical: true,
    interactive: false
});
```

how Can I attach the var titles to the msLinks ... with each title containing a different link

For the code you can review the code on codepen because I can't paste the whole code in here somehow. My apologies

Comment: By using an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rangeContent function, i think it takes a parameter like below:

```
    rangeContent: function (i) {
        //Now you can check your condition and return the specific url;
        return url_array[i];
    },
```

I think that is what you are looking for.

---

***EDITED***

```
var url_array = {
  'namefayee' => ['<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>'], 
  'Champ App' => ['<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>'], 
  'Shirt Design' => ['<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>'], 
  'Post NL' => ['<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>','<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>']
};
```

and then you can do like this:

```
    rangeContent: function (i) {
        //Now you can check your condition and return the specific url;
        
        var urls = '';
        
        switch(i){
          case 1:
            urls = url_array['namefayee'].join(' ') 
            break;
          default:
            urls = '<a class="ms-slide__link">View Case</a>';
            break;
        }
        
        return urls;
    },
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much! You mean like:

   rangeContent: function (i) {
        return https://www.youtube.com_PostNL[i];
    },

or like

 rangeContent: function (i) {
        //Now you can check your condition and return the specific url;
        return url_var titles = [
    'namefayee',
    'Champ App',
    'Shirt Design',
    'Post NL'
];[i];
    },

If its the last one I still have one URL returned and I want 4 URLS for every title one

Comment: So you like to show for example 4 View Case?

Comment: I have edited the question and see if that works for you.

Comment: If it works for you then please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I had one more question.. where in the code should I put it?

Comment: Sorry nvm I have like 8 titles with rangecontent ...

Comment: What does this    urls = url_array['namefayee'].join(' ') 
            break; mean btw ... sorry for all the late questions but I haven't had any time to try this code out